# Why is the mouseenter event listener only working on the first grid-item but is not working on the rest

Tags: javascript

I want the addToCartBar show when the mouse enters the any of the grid-items , it should appear on that grid item only, however it is just working on the first one. What am i doing wrong.

Here is the necessary ejs code

```
<div class="main-cont">  
                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                            <div class="item-img">
                                <img src="/NikeTiempo.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <h5>Category</h5>
                                <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                                <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                            </div>
                    </div>        

                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                            <div class="item-img">
                                <img class="rotated-img" src="/AdidasAce.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <h5>Category</h5>
                                <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                                <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                        <div class="item-img">
                            <img src="/NikeTiempo.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text small-card-text">
                            <h5>Category</h5>
                            <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                            <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                        <div class="item-img">
                            <img src="/NikeTiempo.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text small-card-text">
                            <h5>Category</h5>
                            <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                            <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-5">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                        <div class="item-img">
                            <img src="/NikeTiempo.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text small-card-text">
                            <h5>Category</h5>
                            <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                            <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item grid-item-6">
                        <div class="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
                        <div class="item-img">
                            <img src="/NikeTiempo.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text small-card-text">
                            <h5>Category</h5>
                            <h3 class="product-name">Product Name</h3>
                            <h3 class="price">$200</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the JS for it

```
// //Hover Effect On Grid-Item
let cardItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
let addToCartBar = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart')

for (let cardItem of cardItems) {
    cardItem.addEventListener('mouseenter' , () => {
    addToCartBar.style.display = "flex"
})
    }
```

I know that the above code loops through the array of cardItems and for each one, it applies the function so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you actually change the `display` property of the first card item's button every time because of `let addToCartBar = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart')`. This will traverse the dom and grab the first matching element. In order to achieve what you want you have to query inside each `cardItem` like below:

```
// //Hover Effect On Grid-Item
let cardItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');

for (let cardItem of cardItems) {
    cardItem.addEventListener('mouseenter' , () => {
      let addToCartBar = cardItem.querySelector('.add-to-cart')
      addToCartBar.style.display = "flex"
  })
}
```

Comment: It is still just applying on the first one @fgkolf

Comment: @HadiZouhbi You can check your dev tools or this [demo version](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-tu-p5zdn?file=/src/index.js) and validate that `display:flex` is applied in each add to cart separately.

Answer (score 0):

For the posted code i believe this answers you question:

> The Document method querySelector() returns the **first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

So you are applying the event listeners callback to a single element, you can select multiple elements with the `.querySelectorAll()` .

As well you can use the `hover` css selector which will simplify your code.
You can create a separate css file and link it into your js file or add the snipet directly into your javascript code.

```
.add-to-card:hover {
  //add wanted behaviour here
}
```

You can read more about css selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)